# Obtaining a substring from the parent string

Tags: c

I have receive an array

```
char arry[] ="TestINeedHelp";
```

I am interested in `arry` from 5th char onward. Total length and content of string can vary but I am always interested from 5th char onward.

How can I isolate this part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach would be to enclose the "thing" you need to do in a function:

```
void process_substring(const char *s)
{
}
```

and then from the other context just call the function, passing it a pointer to the substring that starts at the fifth character:

```
if(strlen(arry) >= 5)
  process_substring(&arry[4]);
```

I added code to make sure that `arry` has at least five characters before we try to access the substring.

The expression `&arry[4]` means "take the address of the character at index 4", which is the fifth character. Since that character was inside a string, its address will act as the address of a string that starts with that character.

I did not deal with scope/lifetime issues of `arry`.

Comment: thanks ! process_substring(arry[4]); if i had done this then char at index pass is not passed as reference, right ?

Comment: Yes, but that will give you a compiler error since the character isn't a valid pointer.

Comment: Note that `const char *s` can be a problem if OP wants to modify `arry` inside the function

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [strncpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) function, manual hacking with pointers is not very advisable.

In your case, the function call would look like this:

```
strncpy(dest, src + 4, strlen(src) - 1);
```

Comment: @Gopi ...only if in `dest` no space left for `\0`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes man that's what I meant. Felt not to look too much into it so removed the comment

Answer (score 1):

You can write something like

```
char * p = (char *)arry + 4;
```

and then, you can use `p` in your case.

Also, another approach is to use [`strcpy()`/ `strncpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) like [assuming `p` is already allocated]

```
strcpy(p,&array[4]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
strcpy(subString,array+4);
```

`array+4` points to the 5th element in the array

Comment: 6th element, actually.